# the relation between non negative finite measure space and probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a question please:

Is any true result for a probability space also true for a non-negative finite measure space ?

Comment: As stated, that obviously false, you may have to restrict the question. For instance, any statement or tight inequality involving the fact that the measure of the space is 1 will now fail, by say a constant, if the measure of the space is 2.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it will be true with appropriate constant multipliers.

**Example**: Jensen's inequality for probability space $(X, \cal F, \mu)$:

If $\phi$ is convex, then $\phi\left(\int_X f\;d\mu\right) \le \int_X \phi(f)\;d\mu$.

This may fail for finite measure space.  Example, $X=[-1,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.  Let $\phi(x) = x^2-1$.  Now
$$
\left(\int_{-1}^1 x\;dx\right)^2-1
\le \int_{-1}^1 (x^2-1)\;dx
$$
is the false statement $-1 \le -\frac{4}{3}$.

However, for finite measure space $(X, \cal F, \mu)$, we do have

If $\phi$ is convex, then
$\phi\left(\frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X f\;d\mu\right) \le \frac{1}{\mu(X)}\int_X \phi(f)\;d\mu$.